# Unable to import a JavaScript class file

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I have this class file in JavaScript that I placed inside a form folder:

```
export class FormRegTest {
  constructor(payload) {
    this.payload = payload;
  }
}
```

I have imported it into the root `index.js` file like so:

```
import { FormRegTest } from './forms/FormRegTest';
```

and then created an instance of it inside of `index.js` like so:

```
const formTest = new FormRegTest(payload);
```

Inside of my `app.html` I include the `index.js` file like so:

```
<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
```

but in the console I continue to get the following error:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: may be index.js not found. check the path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `./forms/FormRegTest` cannot be loaded, try including the `.js` file extension. It's common issue where some IDEs do not include the extension.

Comment: its funny because on my own machine I do not have to include the file extension using VS Code, but it seems on this other machine, I do have to include the `.js` extension using VS Code. Thank you.